# Divide xml using xslt with custom nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

Below is my xml excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>Superb story of army veteran</description>
   </book>
   </catalog>
```

I want to split it on the basis of book so that i get this as an output::

```
<Object-bean>
<child-bean>
 <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</child-bean>

<child-bean>
<book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>Superb story of army veteran</description>
   </book>
</child-bean>
</Object-bean>
```

child bean node i need to map with java class through annotation so that there will be list of  child bean node as a string.Here is my java code::

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "Child-bean")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public class ChildBean {
@XmlAttribute(name="price")
private String price;
@XmlAttribute(name="country")
private String country;


public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
```

}

here is my object bean class::

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Object-bean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class ObjectBean {

@XmlAttribute(name = "name")
private String name;
@XmlAttribute
private String id;

@XmlElement(name="Child-bean")
private List<ChildBean> childList = new ArrayList<ChildBean>();
   }
```

Comment: Do any one have idea or solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the relation between your XML and the Java code but in terms of XSLT it looks as if you simply want to wrap each `book` element into a `child-bean` element and you want to transform the root element (`catalog` -> `Object-bean`) so all you need is

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <child-bean>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </child-bean>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
  <Object-bean>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </Object-bean>
</xsl:template>
```